# My Armature problem when exporting models with rigs as GLTF

Tags: export, gltf

I have a problem when I export my mesh with a rig as a GLTF, The model always cresses at the vertexes like this. Can someone help with this. I'm using Blender 3.6 by the way but it still happens on other versions of Blender. [image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.